WPF ContextMenu unable to disable highlighting on mouse over
I am unable to disable the highlight effect on a MenuItem when hovering over it in a WPF ContextMenu. The issue is shown in the image. This only occurs when I bind the ContextMenu to an ItemsSource. When the MenuItems are added directly in XAML, I don’t see this behavior. I've tried several solutions found online, but none of them have worked.
I found a similar issue on StackOverflow here, but I couldn't get the suggested solution to work.
I would really appreciate any help with this.

<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Window.Effect>
    <BlurEffect Radius="10"></BlurEffect>
</Window.Effect>
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FullWidthSeparatorStyle" TargetType="Separator">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Separator">
                    <Border Padding="0" Background="Black" Height="1" Opacity="0.3"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="MenuItemTheme" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,10"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="MenuItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Separator Style="{StaticResource FullWidthSeparatorStyle}"></Separator>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ContextMenuTheme" TargetType="ContextMenu">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="#000000" Opacity="0.53" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.9"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15"/>
        <Setter Property="Effect">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Opacity="0.5" BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="2"/>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContextMenu">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border
                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                 BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                 BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                 Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                 CornerRadius="15" 
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Margin="0"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource MenuItemTheme}"></Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Width="10" Height="10">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu 
                ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}" 
                Style="{StaticResource ContextMenuTheme}" UsesItemContainerTemplate="True">
                <ContextMenu.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="DarkGreen"/>
                </ContextMenu.Resources>
                <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemContainerTemplate>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Title}"/>
                    </ItemContainerTemplate>
                </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
</Grid>

     using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows;
 using System.Windows.Controls;
 using System.Windows.Data;
 using System.Windows.Documents;
 using System.Windows.Input;
 using System.Windows.Media;
 using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
 using System.Windows.Navigation;
 using System.Windows.Shapes;
 
 namespace WpfApp1
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
     /// </summary>
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
     {
         public ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel> MenuItems { get; set; }
 
         public MainWindow()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
 
             MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemModel>
             {
                 new MenuItemModel { Title = "File" },
                 null,
                 new MenuItemModel { Title = "Edit" },
                 new MenuItemModel { Title = "View" },
                 null,
                 new MenuItemModel { Title = "Help" }
             };
 
             DataContext = this;
         }
     }
 
     public class MenuItemModel
     {
         public string Title { get; set; }
     }
 }


This question is similar to: Change Background color of MenuItem on MouseOver.
